# how to add multiple comboboxes to the listbox dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to add the comboboxes + some text to the list box dynamically in C#
it has to display 2 comboboxes + text, but it is showing only text if i written

```
lstboxVideos.Item.Add(subvideo)
```

and it is showing only one combobox if i written

```
lstboxVideos.Controls.Add(subvideo)
```

suggest me how to get back from this problem

```
foreach(var video in videos) 
{
    var subvideos = video.Descendants("subvideos");
    if (subvideos.Count() >= 1) 
    {
        ComboBox subvideo = new ComboBox();
        subvideo.Name = "subvideo" + i;
        subvideo.Items.Add(video.Attribute("name").Value);
        foreach(var videoname in subvideos) 
        {
            subvideo.Items.Add(videoname.Value);
        }
        listBoxVideos.Items.Add(subvideo);
        i++;
    } 
    else 
    {
        listBoxVideos.Items.Add(video.Attribute("name").Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? To show a list of ComboBoxes or Simple Texts, you don't need to use ListBox. You are trying to do a wrong job. If you share the requirement, probably will receive better answers.

Comment: And why don't you use a `TreeView` and show sub videos as child nodes?

Comment: Or if you prefer to use `ComboBox` you can use a `FlowLayoutPanel` or a `TableLayoutPanel` and add your ComboBoxes to it.

Comment: sir why cannot to add combobox to listbox .i want to know the reason sir

Comment: `ListBox` is not designed to be used as a container control. When you need to show a List of Controls, you should use a container to host your controls. You can add controls to ListBox, but it is completely useless.

Comment: thank you so much sir now i got the output, i used flow layout pannel

Comment: if selected index change on one combo box it is affecting to the remaining boxes also sir

Comment: I will provide a sample for you as soon as I can:)

Answer (score 0):

you can add them like this:

```
var cb = new ComboBox();
var t1 = new TextBlock(){Text = "111"};
var t2 = new TextBlock(){Text = "222"};
var t3 = new TextBlock(){Text = "333"};
cb.Items.Add(t1);
cb.Items.Add(t2);
cb.Items.Add(t3);
yourListBox.Items.Add(cb);
```

Comment: Adding a `ComboBox` to a `ListBox.Items` doesn't have any useful result :)

Comment: i have to show some video names in particular place and if that video has sub videos means it has display like a dropdown list this is my task

Comment: @RezaAghaei: first I thought like that too. but when try to create it, it worked! I know it may not useful, but now it seems someone need it!!!

Comment: @aisa It never shows any `ComboBox` in `ListBox` this way. It is a Windows Forms question and this answer may mislead users.

Comment: you'r right, I missed that and assumed it as a wpf app! :D